# How can I resolve a service based upon generic type argument in Castle Windsor?

Tags: entity-framework, generics, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, repository-pattern

I have an installer like this:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {

        //Services
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(ASSEMBLY_NAME)
                .BasedOn<IService>()
                .WithServiceFirstInterface()
                .LifestyleTransient());

        //Repository
        container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>))
                .LifestyleTransient());

        //Contexts
        container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(Context<IGlobalObject>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(GlobalContext<>)).LifestyleTransient());

    }
```

The repository is an open generic, and it has a Context constructor injected, which is a wrapper around an EF DbContext, but takes a type argument to indicate the database it needs to connect to. The idea is that I have several DbContexts as I need to connect to multiple databases, and I want windsor to resolve the appropriate DBcontext based upon the type argument passed to the repository.

The repositories type argument is constrained to the following (GlobalObject and GlobalContext refer to types associated with 1 such database):

```
public interface IGlobalObject : IObject
    {}

    public interface IObject
    {
        int Key { get; set; }
    }
```

However, Windsor cannot resolve the context, and I cannot work out why? It is registered and in the container, but it cannot resolve.

**EDIT:**

Code for GlobalContext:

```
public class GlobalContext<T> : Context<T>
    where T : IGlobalObject
{
    private const string GLOBAL_CSTR = "Global";

    public GlobalContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GLOBAL_CSTR].ConnectionString) {}

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConnectionString> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
//Wrapper around dbcontext which enforces type
    public abstract class Context<T> : DbContext where T : IObject
    {
        protected Context() {}
        protected Context(string connectionString)  : base(connectionString){}
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

If i specify the concrete types for every scenario it works, so it is clearly something to do with matching on the interface.

```
//Contexts
        container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(Context<Server>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(GlobalContext<Server>)).LifestyleTransient());
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem to me:

```
//Contexts
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(Context<IGlobalObject>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(GlobalContext<>)).LifestyleTransient());
```

Here you're saying - when somebody asks for Context inject a GlobalContext<> - the problem being how is windsor meant to know what the generic argument for GlobalContext is.

Its hard to see without seeing your GlobalContext object, but should it be:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(Context<>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(GlobalContext<>)).LifestyleTransient());
```

Comment: This totally makes sense, but sadly didn't work. I've added the code for the Context and GlobalContext. Cheers

Comment: Ok - I think I understand better now, I've made a small edit - removing the generic argument.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a direct answer to your question. But I feel the approach may be wrong.

Considering you repositories are implemented by a generic base `Repository<>` I cant see a clean way of relating the generic Type to the correct context. I think you may need to switch to 'flavoured' repositories with explicit contexts injected into them and/or be more verbose in the way you register your contexts.